# Launch Selenium Grid via GridLauncherV3 in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I need to launch the Selenium Hub and Node via direct a Java Program, I saw examples online for launching it via GridLauncherV3 from Selenium. but I tried to do same it's not finding the class GridLauncherV3 from Selenium Grid.

**Dependency -**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java Code -**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        GridLauncherV3.main(new String[] { "-role", "node", "-hub", "http://localhost:4444/grid/register", "-browser",
                "browserName=chrome", "-port", "5555" });
    }
}
```

It showing error at GridLauncherV3 as `GridLauncherV3 cannot be resolved`

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to import `org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3`?

Comment: Actually, I tried to import but it doesn't import that class, when I tried to add import by myself it shows similar error as above 'The import org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 cannot be resolved'

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose issue resolved, I guess in Selenium 3.11.0 the problem with GridLauncherV3, when I updated Selenium to 3.14.0, it can import the class successfully! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the resolution, it was the problem with the Selenium Server jar 3.11.0, when I upgraded the dependency with the latest jar v3.14.0, it worked successfully!

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```